# How to inject helper class dynamically

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, dependency-injection, angular2-di

I have a component that uses one of two helper classes, like:

```
import {HelperA} ...
import {HelperB} ...
...

@Component({..})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    helper: Helper;     
    constructor(private ref: ElementRef, private device: MyDeviceDetectionService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.device.isMobile) {
            this.helper = new HelperA(this.ref);
        } else {
            this.helper = new HelperB(this.ref);
        }
    }
}
```

I realise that this is hard to unit test, so how can I inject these? Ideally I only need one of them, depending on whether `isMobile` is true or false.

Comment: update the codes for the `HelperA` and `HelperB`

Comment: How about refactor them into a base class? No injection, they are always there, etc. My question, what is your problem with testing?

Comment: I cannot mock the directly imported classes (as far as I know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you can push all of that out to the injector. Assuming the two helpers have a common superclass named `Helper`, use the `useFactory` provider option to create whichever you need:

```
providers: [
  ...,
  { provide: Helper, useFactory: createHelper, deps: [MyDeviceDetectionService, ElementRef] },
]
```

Then the factory would look like:

```
export function createHelper(device: MyDeviceDetectionService, ref: ElementRef): Helper {
  if (device.isMobile) {
    return new HelperA(ref);
  } else {
    return new HelperB(ref);
  }
}
```

Note that this will have to be in the *component's* providers array, as the element reference isn't available at the module level.

Comment: most likely the ElementRef value should be passed into the factory method

Comment: I can pass-in the element ref later (not the constructor), which would make it easier

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri yes, you could have e.g. `this.helper.setRef(this.ref);` at some point if the DI doesn't work; the downside of that is if you forget to do so somewhere then you leave the object in an unusable state.

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri You can, but this will make the pattern considerably more complicated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You can't use `ElementRef` there, it is local compiler dependency that doesn't make sense in root injector. This provider should be specified in component's `providers`, not in module.

Comment: @estus yes, I thought that might be the case; I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: I assume you ment `function` not `class` In my case `Helper` is an interface, which doesn't seem to work very well: `'Helper' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` What is the best solution here ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri I did, yes; fixed. Why not make it a superclass? Otherwise you'll have to use an InjectionToken instead: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectiontoken

Comment: Ok, if they have common code I'll change it into a base-class